# Is $\int_1^2 \frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt t} \, dt$ integrable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt t} \, dt < \infty $ ? How to prove it ?

Thankfully

Comment: Regarding your $<\infty$: $\int_{t_0}^2 \frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt{t}}$ will actually diverge to $-\infty$ as $t_0\to 1^+$, since the denominator is negative then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\cos(t)}{1-\sqrt{t}}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{t})\cos(t)}{1-t}$$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  SCROLL OVER THE HIGHLIGHTED AREA TO REVEAL THE SOLUTION

> Note that for for any $\epsilon >0$ and $x\in (1+\epsilon,3/2]$ we have $$\frac{(1+\sqrt{t})\cos(t)}{1-t}\le \frac{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac32}\right)\cos(3/2)}{1-t}$$and $$\int_{1+\epsilon}^{3/2}\frac{1}{1-t}\,dt=\log(2\epsilon)\to -\infty$$as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  So, the integral of interest diverges.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr MV. I wasn't able to figure out what was the behaviour of $\int_{t_0}^2\frac{1}{1-\sqrt(t)}$ as $t_0 \to 1^+$ and I was trying to transform it into something of the form $\int_0^{...}\frac{1}{\sqrt(t)}$ via a change of variable but I wasn't getting anywhere.
I need to get better at doing theses kind of calculations, if you could point me to a source of exercises I would be very grateful

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

You should check what happens near $1^+$:
$$\frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt t}=\frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt {1+(t-1)}}\sim
\frac{\cos 1}{1-(1+\frac{1}{2}(t-1))}=-\frac{2\cos 1}{t-1}$$
which is NOT integrable. Moreover $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac{\cos t}{1-\sqrt t} \, dt = -\infty$ because $-2\cos 1<0$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the integral is convergent, the integral
$$ \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2z}{1-z}\,\cos(z^2)\,dt $$
is convergent, too, due to the substitution $t=z^2$. However, the last integrand function is a meromorphic function with a simple pole at $z=1$ with residue $-2\cos(1)$, hence the last integral *is not* convergent and neither it is the original one.